# How can I make an angularjs button click call a passed-in function?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to make an application that has some data-driven UI. So, I'm trying to pass in a function that should be called when a button is clicked. The second button works, of course, as it explicitly calls the function. However, the first one doesn't.
Here's the angular js code:

```
$scope.clickFunction = "clickedIt()";
$scope.clickedIt = function(){
    alert("It worked!");}
```

And the html:

```
<p>How can I make this button call a passed-in function?</p>
<button ng-click="{{clickFunction}}">Click Me</button>
<p>I'd like it to evaluate to this, which works.</p>
<button ng-click="clickedIt()">Click Me</button>
```

Here's a plunker with the code I'm try to make work.
http://plnkr.co/edit/aRBX3bbgHCV15mgROZx1?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a function name in controller you want to use as event handler:

```
$scope.clickFunction = "clickedIt";
```

then in template use bracket notation:

```
<button ng-click="this[clickFunction]()">Click Me</button>
```

The idea is that `this` points to current scope object, exactly what you want, and that's why bracket notation is useful here.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/TmdGuCpnbYz3gaWDi9tB?p=preview

Comment: I've never seen bracket notation before. Time to hit the angularjs documentation again. Thanks!

Comment: You will not find it in Angular documentation though. You just need to understand that angular expression is basically parsed and evaluated, as javascript. And javascript has this feature: you can access object property with bracket notation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation